# Don't show data notices in worksheet

Tags: ruby, axlsx

I'm aware of data validations in Axlsx, however I'm not sure that's what I'm looking for here. I don't want to validate any data per se, but want any cell notices (in Excel here) to to be ignored.

For example, a notice I'm seeing on a couple of cells is:

```
The number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe.
```

I tried doing something like this to select the whole worksheet and avoid showing any validation erros, however it didn't work for me:

```
sheet.add_data_validation("A1:H100", {
  showErrorMessage: false
 })
```

Can I use a Data validation to avoid displaying these notices in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the error checking options found in Excel Options ► Formulas ► Error checking rules ► Numbers formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe. (or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>,<kbd>T</kbd>,<kbd>F</kbd> then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)

To halt the display of these error control messages through VBA, run the following line of code.

```
Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.NumberAsText = False
```

Comment: Thanks, however this is using the Ruby gem, Axlsx. Maybe I'll remove the Excel tag.